# How to automatically resize iframe content size when browser window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am now making a website which will display a spot on a map(not google map). I used an iframe to contain the map and I would like the map to resize the width according to browser window width.

This is my code:

```
<iframe width='1800' height='300' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://f.amap.com/xxxxxxxxxx'></iframe>
```

To resize the iframe, I simply changed the width and height of the iframe using jquery code like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
var window_width = $(window).width();
$('iframe').width(window_width);
});
```

However, it changes the width of the iframe only and the contents cannot be resized. How can I resize the content when the window resizes? Thank you very much!

Comment: The resizing of the iframe part doesn’t need JS, you can simply specify a width of 100% via CSS. But if the map doesn’t automatically adapt, then you might need to reload the whole thing after a resize. (But that should be properly _throttled_ then, otherwise you will be firing a massive amount of requests.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is restricted from making changes to the content of an iframe. If you control the site inside the iframe, you can set up a message-system between the two sites. It might be worth checking if one exists even if you don't control the other site.

Otherwise, I would recommend simply refreshing the content of the iframe:

```
$( '#iframe' ).attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });
```

As misorude mentioned in a comment you should contain this line so it doesn't fire immediately upon resize, since that would send an unreasonable amount of requests to the remote site.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set the **max-width property** to *100%*.

```
<iframe width='1800' height='300' style="max-width:100%" frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://f.amap.com/xxxxxxxxxx'> 
</iframe>
```

this will *resize* according to the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `width: 100%` with CSS.
check this : http://jsfiddle.net/w8xeotv4/

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're not running into CORS issues and the target site is responsive, you can try something like this

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var window_width = $(window).width();
  $('iframe').width(window_width);
  $('iframe').contents().width(window_width);
});
```

***Edit***

Sorry, this was a very bad answer, not sure what I was thinking when I wrote this. The accepted answer is the best way to go about it.